# Как сделать ввод объектов в Swagger?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, swagger

У меня есть 2 объекта, например статья и пользователь:

```
public class Article
{
    [Key, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Viewer { get; set; }
    public List<string> LikeUsers { get; set; }
    public List<string> DislikeUsers { get; set; }
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public User UserCreate { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    [Key, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Когда я делаю на ввод метода объект Article, то в Swagger пишется оба объекта, как поступить чтобы писались, только нужные строчки??

```
ActionResult<Article> AddArticle([FromBody]Article article)
```

Создать отдельный объект для заполнения нужных строчек или JObject сделать на вход и оттуда брать нужные данные, но тогда не понятно как в swagger записать правильные данные?

Comment: А причем тут swagger? Поймите Swagger это не программа это спецификация. Вы описываете сервис. Swagger как описание спецификации может быть подключено к сервису.

Comment: Если Вам нужно объекты в той или иной форме следите за сериализацией объектов.

Comment: @AzizUmarov, я хотел спросить, наверно глупый вопрос, потому что кому как удобно тот так и делает.
В примерах asp.net много методов, которые принимают объект. Но у меня все эти объекты связаны, с другими, и в итоге в Swagger, когда я пишу такое, получается много лишнего.

Как тогда поступить, написать только переменные которые нужны? или объект создать специально для запроса?